# Why the Rigidbody player controller is not working ? I can't move the player around

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This script is attached to my player that have a rigidbody component.
The rigidbody use gravity and is kinematic are set to ture.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RigidbodyPlayercontroller : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody rb;
    public float speed;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float mH = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float mV = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        rb.velocity = new Vector3(mH * speed, rb.velocity.y, mV * speed);
    }
}
```

But the player is not moving it does nothing. I tried speed value 1 and also 100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the `velocity` of a kinematic Rigidbody doesn't cause any effect. Like the documentation says, use [MovePosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html) to change the position of a kinematic [Rigidbody](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html).

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController: MonoBehaviour
{
   public float speed;

   private float vertical;
   private float horizontal;

   private Rigidbody rb;

   void Start()
   {
      rb = GetComponent < Rigidbody > ();
   }

   void Update()
   {
      vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed;
      horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed;
   }

   void FixedUpdate()
   {
      rb.MovePosition(
         transform.position +
         transform.right * horizontal * Time.fixedDeltaTime +
         transform.forward * vertical * Time.fixedDeltaTime
      );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it's a 2d or 3d game? i don't know much about 3d games, but that code seems to be like a 2d game controller, tell me if i'm wrong and i may help you

Comment: It's a 3d game.